# R - How to group and sum rows with multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, grouping

this seems like something that should be really easy to do but for some reason no method seems to be working for me. I have a dataframe which lists a bunch of sample IDs on the rows and a whole list of Fungal species on the columns. One column lists the regions that the samples are located in. I would like to group the rows into their regions and then sum their values for each column.
Here is the code I have tried (and the errors they produce):

```
heatMapTable2 <- aggregate(x = heatMapTable[ , 2:ncol(heatMapTable)], by = heatMapTable[,1], FUN = sum)

Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  arguments must have same length

heatMapTable2 <- aggregate(x = heatMapTable[ , 2:ncol(heatMapTable)], by = heatMapTable$sampEcoReg, FUN = sum)

Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
  'by' must be a list

library(dplyr)
heatMapTable[,2:ncol(heatMapTable)] %>%
group_by(heatMapTable$sampEcoReg) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum))

Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"
```

A csv of the dataframe I am trying to sort can be found [here](https://otagouni-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/lassa109_student_otago_ac_nz/EeGurryaRklEntap70ww8ggBe3yS07wZBqUCYtCCqml9XA?e=gH4GXQ)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling to figure this out for hours! Thank you!

For some reason it keeps thinking the heatMapTable isn't a dataframe and I have to coerce it back. The following gives a different error that might shed more light?

```
heatMapTable <- as.data.frame(heatMapTable)
library(dplyr)
heatMapTable %>% 
    group_by(sampEcoReg) %>% 
    summarize_all(sum) %>%
    as.data.frame()

Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `NR_157889_Cortinarius_cremeolina`.
ℹ `NR_157889_Cortinarius_cremeolina = .Primitive("sum")(NR_157889_Cortinarius_cremeolina)`.
x invalid 'type' (list) of argument
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: sampEcoReg = "Lakes".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: It would really help to work with sample data. Can you provide the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is just enough of your `heatMapTable` that we can still reproduce the issue without flooding the screen with lots of data? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `group_by() %>% summarize_all()` from dplyr:

```
heatMapTable %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    group_by(sampEcoReg) %>% 
    summarize_all(sum) %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Cheers for your help mate!
I got the same error as when I tried to use dplyr before:

Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"

Comment: What's class is heatMapTable? The same error when you add ```heatMapTable %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by()...```?

Comment: So not sure why but for some reason the class of heatMapTable keeps changing from data.frame. I coerced it back using as.data.frame() and ot another error. I just added that to the comment

Answer (score 0):

We can use `across` to sum each grouped column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

#data obtained from https://otagouni-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/lassa109_student_otago_ac_nz/EeGurryaRklEntap70ww8ggBe3yS07wZBqUCYtCCqml9XA?rtime=yqv_AETh2Ug
heatMapTable <- read_xlsx('heatMapTableEcoReg.xlsx')

heatMapTable %>% 
    group_by(sampEcoReg) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))



# A tibble: 21 × 2,778
   sampEcoReg     NR_157889_Corti… NR_172327_Corti… ASV2557_Cortina…
   <chr>                     <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 Aspiring                      0                0               15
 2 Canterbury Fo…                0                0                0
 3 Catlins                       0                0                0
 4 Fiord                         0                0                0
 5 Hawdon                        0                0                0
 6 Heron                         0                0                0
 7 Lakes                         0                0                0
 8 Lammerlaw                     0                0                0
 9 MacKenzie                     0                0                0
10 Mavora                        0                0                0
# … with 11 more rows, and 2,774 more variables:
#   ASV40605_Cortinarius_sp. <dbl>, MK838250 <dbl>,
#   ASV44745_Cortinarius_comptulus <dbl>,
#   ASV14648_Cortinarius_comptulus <dbl>,
#   ASV15995_Cortinarius_sp. <dbl>, ASV26274_Cortinarius_sp. <dbl>,
#   MW341317_Cortinarius_vernus <dbl>,
#   KX355517_Cortinarius_vernus <dbl>, …
```

Is that the desired output?